# embeding html5 custom player on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, html, youtube, embedding, facebook-opengraph

when you shared a youtube video on the facebook wall. The html5 video player is customized. Is this only for youtube?

I understand now you can specify the fallback video files sources in the meta tags. However, i would also like to have custom html5 player when sharing a video on iPad, not just a regualr html5 video player.

What should I do to get it working for my site?

Comment: Have you searched before posting your question? [Share HTML5 player on Facebook wall](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8708233/share-html5-player-on-facebook-wall)

Comment: BTW, you just can't embed custom player if it's not flash! Only the video.

Comment: then how does the soundcloud do it